# Padding-left doesn't work

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC2 application test application. The master page code's structure likes:

```
<div id="mainContainer"> 
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="leftColPlaceHolder" runat="server"> 
        <div id="leftcolumn"> 
            <div class="links"> 
                <div class="padding_left"> 
                    blah blah 
                </div> 
            </div> 
            <div class="innertube"> 
              blah blah 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"> 
        <div id="contentwrapper"> 
            <div id="contentcolumn"> 
               blah blah                </div> 
        </div> 
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 
</div>
```

In a view index.aspx, the code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server"> 
<h2><%: ViewData["Message"] %></h2> 
<p> 
    To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>. 
</p>
```

I want to h2 part padding left, but it doesn't work at all. Please see my CSS:

```
#maincontainer{
width: 840px; /*Width of main container*/
margin: 0 auto; /*Center container on page*/
}

#topsection{
background: #EAEAEA;
height: 90px; /*Height of top section*/
}

#topsection h1{
margin: 0;
padding-top: 15px;
}

#contentwrapper{
float: left;
width: 100%;
}

#contentcolumn{
margin-left: 300px; /*Set left margin to LeftColumnWidth*/
}

#leftcolumn
{
    float: left;
    width: 300px; /*Width of left column*/
    background: #C8FC98;
}

#footer
{
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #666699;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px 0;
 }

  #footer a{
  color: #FFFF80;
  }

  .innertube{
  /*Margins for inner DIV inside each column (to provide padding)*/
    margin-top: 0;
   }

  .links
  {
      width: 300px;
      height: 541px; /* must be 541px to display full image */
      background-image: url('../../cross.jpg');
  } 

  h2
  {
      padding-left: 55px;
      background-color: #00FFFF;
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the page rendering in quirks mode by any chance??

Comment: On which browsers is this problem affective?

Comment: It is wise to see if other browsers (chrome and firefox) have the same problem, which is not very likely. 
If not so, than there is a high chance you have to build a fix for IE, one of these can be changing the default redering mode as Nicholas mentioned. 
Could you Hit f12 in IE9 and see what the default documentation mode is?

Comment: what mode is ie9 claiming to be rendering in? press F12 while viewing the page

Comment: Even I force to add  <h2 style="padding-left:55px;"><%= ViewData["Message"] %></h2>, it is still not working. The mode:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

Comment: ie9 to a degree ignores the doctype you need to find out what mode it thinks the page needs to be rendered in by pressing F12 and listing the browser mode and document mode.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/16/ie-s-compatibility-features-for-site-developers.aspx

Comment: And if you "Select element by click" (ctrl + b) the H2 element, do yo you see in the develop console (f12) that the padding from the css is coming trough?

Comment: can you post a fiddle up with your rendered code in it?

Comment: As Nicholas said I would like to see a full rendered example of the this page which is not working, I made a small demo html file which has no problems in the situation as described above (http://pastebin.com/mt5CA69m)

Answer (score 0):

I copied the style and created a HTML file with:

`<h2><%: ViewData["Message"] %></h2> 
<p> 
    To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>. 
</p>`

It seem to be working fine. If you are on Chrome or Firefox try right-clicking on the text and inspect element to check if has taken the style. It could be the case that you have several h2 styles for different classes. find the right h2 by changing the css attributes and tracking the changes on the page. When you found the right one go to the css file on the same line to correct the style.

As a really fast solution (not a good practice though) you can change your h2 tag into:

`<h2 style="padding-left: 55px;"></h2>`

Hope this helps.

Comment: These are the suggestions he actualy all tried before (see comments under his initial post)

Comment: I think mine was sent prior to those

Comment: No offence mate, but thats what the timestamps are, check again.

Answer (score 0):

The padding works as it should. i was going to attach a screen shot but don't have enough reputation point to do so. With padding left you would see the text indented by 55px and the blue background would start at 0.

If you want the whole h2 area to be indented then you should be using margin-left: 55px;

I hope this helps!